# iteration to construct a function between two arrays in ocamlre

Tags: arrays, function, iteration, ocaml

I have question regarding constructing a function like this.

Here, I have two lists, both have the same length (say that the length is `n`, and the case that I want is a function which fulfil this requirement:

```
list1.(0) -> list2.(0)
list1.(1) -> list2.(1)
...
list1.(n-1) -> list2.(n-1)
```

How to do it? Should I do iteration inside a function (and how)? Or appending two functions (and how)? There must be tricky way to answer thing like this.

Sorry, have to answer this by myself. I just find that this is actually quite easy. I can easily create a function `f` which is written by nlucaroni much shorther.

```
let rec f domain range x =
match (List.hd domain) = x with
    | true -> (List.hd range)
    | false -> f (List.tl domain) (List.tl range) x;;
```

Comment: Can you try to clarify? I don't understand what function do you want to construct -- just that it's over two lists of equal length.

Comment: Realize that Lists and Arrays are completely different in OCaml.

Comment: @akoprowski: I want to make a function, in which if the n-th argument of the list1 is the input, I will return the n-th argument of the list2. Moreover I will use this function as an argument in another function.

Comment: @nlucaroni: sorry, I do mean list, I just wrote the wrong code there, it should have been something like (List.nth 0 list1) -> (List.nth 0 list2) and so on.

Comment: `Lists` really change my answer; you should examine what `lukstafi` said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you have two arrays. One defines the domain of the function, another the range. And you want to write an ocaml function that represents this function. I am assuming here that the function is bijective. The missing part, the meat, is a function to find the index of an element in an array. In the spirit of `List.find`, I decided to pass a function to define this comparison.

```
let find_index p array =
    let rec find_index idx =
        if idx = (Array.length array) then raise Not_found
        else if (p array.(idx)) then idx
        else find_index (idx+1)
    in
    find_index 0
```

From here it is trivial to create the function, and its inverse,

```
let f domain range x = range.(find_index (fun y -> 0 = compare x y) domain)
let f' domain range y = domain.(find_index (fun x -> 0 = compare x y) range)
```

There is a better way if you plan on using this on more then just a small set of data. Really, this is a poor implementation for a `Map` --this has O(n) lookup, while a map would have O(log(N)). I realize you may not be interested in alternatives, so I will leave my recommendation at that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will change a little since I need to use <code>f</code> as a parameter in my code.

Comment: my data will not so big, so changing the complexity from O(n) to O(log(n)) will not affect too much for now. In any case, the O(n) is still tractable :)

Comment: post updated! I just realized that this is actually quite easy

Comment: Since you are dealing with lists it may be a good idea to use `List.combine` and `List.assc`. You will generate a tuple, ('a,'b) to represent the pairs. _edit_ I see lukstafi mentioned them a few hours ago. It's definitely a more natural way to create the association.

Comment: @Zfm, good, it is pretty easy. Glad whatever was necessary clicked.

Answer (score 2):

There is an `if` expression you know, save the `match` expression for lists and other data structures so that you don't need to use the unsafe functions `List.hd` and `List.tl`! For example your code rewrites to (ETA: oops, forgot the recursive call):

```
let rec f domain range x =
match domain, range with
  | k::_, v::_ when k = x -> v
  | _::ks, _::vs -> f ks vs x
  | _ -> raise Not_found;;
```

Another approach would be to use the standard library functions:

```
let f domain range =
  let map = List.combine domain range in
  fun x -> List.assoc x map;;
```